# match the column value based on previous paired values in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary, mapping

i have one dictionary with pair of keys and values and list

```
dict={0.000806:1.341382,0.023886:39.63012,7.525935:63.89669,7.571048:62.47208}
list=[7.525935,7.571048,0.000806,0.023886]
```

with this following list and dictionaries my expected output is
expected output:

```
    {7.525937:63.89669,
    7.571048:62.47208,
    0.000806:1.341382, 
    0.023886:0.023886}
```

```
thing_category=dict((t,c) for c,t in category_thing.items())
list=[7.525935,7.571048,0.000806,0.023886]
for stuff in list_of_things:
    if stuff in category_thing:
        print(stuff)
```

with the help of list values match the dictionary values how can i do that i tried merge and map also but it didn't worked
[with help of this 2 columns i have to match the values with another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcO1P.png)[expecting matched values with help of values in first figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C27iI.png)

Comment: Your code has severe formatting issues. This causes substantial issues with troubleshooting Python programs. Please correct this.

Comment: It is unclear what your itterables 'list_of_things' and 'category_thing' actually are.

Comment: kindly check the screenshots

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comprehension to construct a new dict with keys in the order of the list_ entries:

```
dict_ = {0.000806:1.341382,0.023886:39.63012,7.525935:63.89669,7.571048:62.47208}
list_ = [7.525935,7.571048,0.000806,0.023886]

{k: dict_[k] for k in list_}
```

However, you might run into problems with float keys if there are slight numeric differences.

Comment: with this following code iam getting name error "name 'v' is not defined"

Comment: has since been updated. sorry 'bout that.

Comment: now i got the output thanks for the response

Comment: with the above data i have similar data which is large while applying this code i am getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' if you dont mine i can share the two dataframes also

Comment: please feel free to share. Also, it would good to know more about the context, to see whether you are actually on the right track.

Comment: unable to share the file here sir

Comment: if you dont mind can you send me your mail id so will share the files

Comment: make a smaller example and add it to the original question by editing

Comment: if i make smaller example also i will get the output but iam not getting the output with my large data sir

Comment: edited screen shots of my two files

Comment: @AparnaAppu Regarding your TypeError... Python dictionary keys must be hashable. Python lists are not hashable. Depending on your use-case you may be able to convert your list to a tuple (which **is** hashable)

Comment: tried with tuple even though getting hashable type error